# knitr xtable make two tables equal width

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I am using knitr and xtables to automate a report procedure. I want to include a few tables in this report and make them displayed with equal width. The Rnw code is listed below. Anyone could tell me how to make the tables of different column numbers showed of the same width in page?

thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

<<do_table,echo=FALSE, results = "asis">>=
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
mydf1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10),var3=rnorm(10))
print(xtable(mydf))
print(xtable(mydf1))
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the tabularx package, see tabularx [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) for how to use align to further refine your formatting

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

<<do_table,echo=FALSE, results = "asis">>=
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
mydf1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10),var3=rnorm(10))
print(xtable(mydf,align="XXXX"), tabular.environment = 'tabularx', width="3in")
print(xtable(mydf1,align="XXXXX"), tabular.environment = 'tabularx', width="3in")
@

\end{document}
```